# Use Ansible include_tasks with tags on the sub-tasks

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

> **Ansible 2.8.1**

In my playbook `tasks/` dir:

```
main.yml
dev.yml
```

In `main.yml` I have a block like this:

```
- include_tasks: dev.yml
  when: ec2_tag_env == 'dev'
```

**It works fine**

---

**However, if I try to call a specific task within dev.yml using a tag. It won't qualify the task during the run**

For example, this tagged task within `dev.yml`:

```
- name: Pull the latest image
  docker_image:
    name: "{{ dev_image }}"
    source: pull
  tags:
    - container
```

When I run the playbook with `-t container` **it will NOT qualify since the `include_tasks` step doesn't have that tag.**

---

Adding the tag to `include_tasks` will of course fix the problem, but I would then need to keep track of tags as they get added to sub-tasks and add them here as well:

```
- include_tasks: dev.yml
  when: ec2_tag_env == 'dev'
  tags:
    - container
```

**Questions**

- Is it possible to have Ansible just "know" what tasks are within the `include_tasks` block and pull the applicable tags?
- What's the best practice for achieving this goal?

What I would prefer to **not** have to do:

- Put everything `main.yml`. I have so many tasks in this playbook I really want to keep them organized in files.
- Tag all my `include_tasks` blocks with all its sub-tags manually. Sounds like a nightmare to manage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Q: ***"Is it possible to have Ansible just 'know' what tasks are within the include_tasks block and pull the applicable tags?"***

A: What is inside included task will be available after the control flow reaches the *`include_task`* statement and the file is included. See the examples below under the line. For example, such tags won't be included in the list of available tags. See option *`--list-tags`* of *ansible-playbook*. In this respect, the answer is no. But, such tags may be available (after the control flow reaches the *`include_task`* statement) if also specified on the level of the *include_task*. Also, the special tag [*always*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#special-tags-always-and-never) makes such tags available.

Q: ***"What's the best practice for achieving this goal?"***

A: There are two options:

- Either use *`import_tasks`*. The imports are read when the playbook starts.
- Or, use the special tag [*always*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tags.html#special-tags-always-and-never). Ansible will always include the tasks from the file.

---

To clarify the differences. Given the file below

```yaml
shell> cat install.yml
- debug:
    msg: Task 2
  tags: t2
- debug:
    msg: Task 3
  tags: t3
```

1. The playbook

```yaml
shell> cat pb1.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Task 1
      tags: t1
    - include_tasks:
        file: install.yml
```

works as expected

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb1.yml

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Task 1

TASK [include_tasks] *************************************************************************
included: /export/scratch/tmp8/test-828/install.yml for localhost

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Task 2

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Task 3

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

When the tags are used *`-t t1,t2`*, the task tagged t1 is executed, but the task tagged t2 is not because the file is not included

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb1.yml -t t1,t2

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Task 1

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Note that, when started, the application knows nothing about the tags in the included file

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb1.yml --list-tags

playbook: pb1.yml

  play #1 (localhost): localhost    TAGS: []
      TASK TAGS: [t1]
```

---

2. Tag *always* the task *include_tasks*

```yaml
shell> cat pb2.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Task 1
      tags: t1
    - include_tasks:
        file: install.yml
      tags: always
```

When started, the application still knows nothing about the tags in the included file but the tasks will be always included

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb2.yml --list-tags

playbook: pb1.yml

  play #1 (localhost): localhost    TAGS: []
      TASK TAGS: [always, t1]
```

When the tags *`-t t1,t2`* are used now both tasks tagged t1 and t2 are executed

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb2.yml -t t1,t2

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Task 1

TASK [include_tasks] *************************************************************************
included: /export/scratch/tmp8/test-828/install.yml for localhost

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Task 2

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

3. The tag *always* causes that the file *install.yml* will always be included when the control flow reaches the *include_task* statement. But this tag applies to the *include_task* only. It's not inherited by the tasks inside the file. If you want to apply tags to the tasks inside the file use the parameter *apply*. For example

```yaml
shell> cat pb3.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Task 1
      tags: t1
    - include_tasks:
        file: install.yml
        apply:
          tags: install
      tags: always
```

Note that also here, when started, the application knows nothing about both the applied tags and the tags in the included file

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb3.yml --list-tags

playbook: pb3.yml

  play #1 (localhost): localhost    TAGS: []
      TASK TAGS: [always, t1]
```

The only difference caused by the applied tag is that all included tasks can be triggered by this tag, e.g.

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb3.yml -t install

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [include_tasks] *************************************************************************
included: /export/scratch/tmp8/test-828/install.yml for localhost

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Task 2

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: Task 3

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

But, the applied tags won't help you in triggering the included tasks separately. It is also good to understand that the applied tags make no sense without the same tags, or special tag *always*, on the *include_task* level.

Comment: Do I understand this correctly?  That the apply: tag: construct makes each task inside the included task file act as if it has the applied tag(s)?  Would putting `tags: 'install'` on each task inside install.yml be similar to applying the 'install' tag on the include_task?

Comment: Exactly! This is the purpose of `apply: tags`. This substitutes the missing inheritance of tags on the `include_tasks` level.

Answer (score 9):

Kind of an old question, but for others who might struggle because they want or need to use `include_tasks` instead of `import_tasks`. To those who can use both, I would also highly recommend to use `import_tasks` like it was [answered before](https://serverfault.com/a/1023403/501792):

In the official [Ansible manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_tasks_module.html), the developers propose to use `tags: always` on `include_tasks` itself while applying other tags with `apply:` to the included tasks.

See this example (copied [from the manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_tasks_module.html#examples)):

```yaml
- name: Apply tags to tasks within included file
  include_tasks:
    file: install.yml
    apply:
      tags:
        - install
  tags:
    - always
```

This way ensures that Ansible will always (except when called with `--skip-tags always`) include the external tasks to be able to look at those specific tags, so if `install.yml` includes a task with `tags: download` this task will be run if Ansible was called with `--tags download` (without adding `install`).

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend the post about this from Red Hat: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ansible-tags-fast-playbook-runs

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/534791)